# How to remove QueryBuilder placeholders in Doctrine2?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Let's suppose i have the following piece of code:

```
        $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->add('select', 'a')
            ->add('from', 'Entities\Patientprofile a')
            ->add('where', 'a.userid=?1')
            ->setParameter(1, $patientId);
        ;
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $patientProfile = $query->getResult(3);
```

Doctrine adds "u" prefix to all of the results entities as stated [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query),which is undesirable.

Is there any native doctrine methods/solutions to remove these placeholders from results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear in your code, but I'm guessing you're using getScalarResult() to execute your query. In my experience, Doctrine only affixes the alias prefix when you are using scalar hydration to return your results, as explained [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html?highlight=prefix#scalar-hydration). If you use one of the object hydration methods, the prefix should go away. Doctrine's object hydration methods are getResult(), getSingleResult(), and getArrayResult().

Which hydration mode are you using, and does switching it to one of the above methods solve your problem?

Comment: i just updated my qs. you may see my exact query.This query returns an array.

Comment: i replaced getResult(3) with getArrayResult() and as you mentioned, the prefix is gone.thanks for the response.